# Not understanding Java bracket array correctly?

Tags: java, arrays

I was programming a plugin in Java and I wanted to set 4 different `Location` objects. Because in school(C++) they taught us to use [] and I like them (brackets), I decided to do that. Oh boy, I was wrong(or maybe it was just my mistake) I came up with this code:

```
Location[] pos = new Location[4]; //an array (I guess)
Location loc = e.getBlock().getLocation(); //to get the position of a block
```

and then I set it in a for loop to iterate trough them like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    pos[i] = loc;
}
```

But! When I wanted to change any of the `pos[x]` variables, all of them changed. Could this be related to pointers or something?
Anyways. I changed my code to do it like this

```
Location loc = e.getToBlock().getLocation();
Location loc1 = e.getToBlock().getLocation();
Location loc2 = e.getToBlock().getLocation();
Location loc3 = e.getToBlock().getLocation();
```

This code fortunately works, but how would I go with more variables, what if I wanted something like 200 of them? Or maybe a dinamic "array".
You might be wondering why I said "array" in quotes, but I really have no idea how to call `pos[]` other than an array, even tho I know that an Array exists and it's something completely different.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Call `getLocation` inside your for loop. Right now it's only being called once.

Comment: Uhh.. you set them all `loc`. Why is it a surprise that when you change `loc`, they all change?

Comment: Did you change `loc` ? If you did, all `pos[i]` referring to `loc` will change.

Comment: If you want a dynamic array use ArrayList

Comment: Does `e.getToBlock().getLocation();` return a different object each time?

Comment: @SteveSmith It does... But the thing I was doing didn't :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a new Location object at each iteration in the for loop.

Now you are using the same object in all the array slots. The 'loc' variable is a reference to the object in the heap, so changing it spreads the changes to all the array,

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for... That's what I didn't know... I thought that by doing pos[i] = loc I was setting the value of loc, but now I know that I was setting the Object...

Answer (score 1):

They all changed because you set them all to be the same object: the one you assigned to `loc`.  If you had put the call to `e.getToBlock().getLocation()` inside the loop, your 4 array elements would have been different objects.

Comment: @SteveSmith That doesn't square with things working properly when the results of each call are put in distinct variables.

Comment: Thanks... I just thought that I was setting the value not the reference to an object... :P

Answer (score 1):

Right now your `getLocation` function is only being called once which creates a single object. Call it inside your for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    Location loc = e.getBlock().getLocation(); //to get the position of a block
    pos[i] = loc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thought that I was setting the value, not a reference!

Answer (score 1):

> When I wanted to change any of the pos[x] variables, all of them changed

It's because you assign each element of your `pos` to same object. You are from C++ background, so you should have a knowledge about pointers. What you are doing is assigining a "pointer" to same object in all positions of `pos`.

> what if I wanted something like 200 of them?

I am not sure if I understand you right. You can use an `ArrayList` which allows you to add elements dynamically, so you don't have to know its size in advance. Look at [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E)).

Comment: Thanks, I do have some limited knowledge to pointers, but the thing I was missing was that when I was doing pos[i] = loc, it was setting the reference to an object... And I thought it was setting the value...

Comment: Glad I could help with this :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you intend to assign for all the array items the same object `loc`?

If yes, here we go. As others suggest, you should call the function `e.getBlock().getLocation()` once each time you go through your loop. This gives different objects with the same value.

Another workaround is to copy the object, rather than only assign the reference. 
What I think about your problem is that you are mixing copying and assignment. When you assign `loc` to the array items in your loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
pos[i] = loc;
}
```

you assign it by reference, as it an object and not [a primitive data type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

This means that the array items, after you assigned `loc`, have a only a reference to a memory position, when you change its value via any reference, all other references will have the new value, expected behaviour.

If you intend to initiate all the items of your array to `loc`, you should deep/shallow copy it, i.e., not assign it by reference. See here for an explanation [on difference between copy and assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858510/assigning-in-java). Here is an answer for [deep copy using serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java)

Comment: Thanks, I just thought that I was smart and optimized by calling e.getblock().getLocation() only once :D