# Java Character Array Max Capacity

Tags: java

I'm trying to write some code in Java revolving around a Char Array and have some questions, starting with the 1st one below. If possible anywhere in the code, I prefer to use Java 8 and avoid using loops. Please help and thank you.

Question 1: Print out the max capacity for a character array.

```
// Create a character array that can hold a max of 10 elements and copy 
over the contents from another character array.

char[] charArr1 = {'A','B','C'};
char[] charArr2 = new char[10];
charArr2 = charArr1.clone();

// I wanted the result below to be 10, but the output was 3.

System.out.println(charArr2.length);
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: `charArr2 = ...` is an assignment (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858510/assigning-in-java), so `new char[10]` disappears

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
char[] charArr2 = new char[10];
charArr2 = charArr1.clone();
```

You assume:

> I wanted the result below to be 10, but the output was 3.

Your problem is that `clone()` doesn't do what you think it does. You think that it **copies** the content of one array into another. But that is not what happens. Instead:

> When the clone method is invoked upon an array, it returns a reference to a new array which contains (or references) the same elements as the source array.

(from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14149844/1531124)).

If you want to **keep** the array that you created using `new char[10];` you will have to use [System.arraycopy()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) for example. That call keeps the target array, copies in values from some source array.